# Using render() with datatables without data array or preexisting html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'd like to build a `DataTable` with deferred rendering and my `data` is not in a row based format the DataTables would like.  Ideally I'd just like to set a `render()` function that pulls in the right value for the col/row coordinate.

It seems that DataTables requires a `data` input (or prexisting `<tr>` and `<td>`, which is contrary to deferred rendering)

Is it possible to just set the dimensions of the table?  I haven't found an option.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest weight solution I've found is to pass in a sparse `Array` of `Uint8Array`'s.  (Datatables seems to object to the undefined entries in the sparse array):

```
// Not sparse, but at least only 1 byte per cell.   
var empty_row = new Uint8Array(1000)                                  
var data = _.range(1000).map(function() {                               
    return empty_row // We can reuse this array in every row.
})
```

This creates a million cell table by reusing each row.

Then the `render()` function can simply use the meta.col and meta.row information to create the actual data:

```
var render = function(data, type, row, meta) {                          
    return meta.col + '/' + meta.row                                    
}
```

In a practical example, meta.col and meta.row would be used to lookup the actual data that might not be in a row/col format.